# importing javax packages into python

Tags: java, python, linux

I have (what I hope is) a very simple question.

I would like to use some javax.crypto classes from within a python script, so be able to do something like:

```
from javax.crypto import Cipher

cipher = Cipher.getInstance('AES/CTR/NoPadding')
```

But I am not familiar with how to do this get python to be able to recognise java packages, at the moment python, of course, simply says:

> ImportError: No module named
>   javax.crypto

Is it simply a case of adding some variable to $PYTHONPATH or is this just completely wrong?

Many Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You might want to look at Jython (the Python language implemented in Java).  Other than that it's befuddling why you'd even expect this to work.  Java classes are byte-compiled into a form which can be loaded and interpreted by a Java VM (virtual machine) while the most common implementation of Python (CPython) is an interpreter for the native machine.

Comment: "or is this just completely wrong?" --- I'm thinking that your question is framed in some fundamental misconceptions about how Java, and native executables work on your system.

Comment: @Jim: Actually, CPython uses a VM as well. It just doesn't usually have a JITer like Java VMs usually do.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'm aware that CPython implements a VM; however it's not intended to be compatible with Java's VM and CPython couldn't be reasonable expected to interpret Java bytecodes (though Python also implements its own byte code compilation)

Answer (score 2):

It's very completely wrong. Python and Java are separate languages, and CPython, the implementation you're using, has its own VM. Use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) if you want to bridge the two.

Answer (score 1):

Under jython you use the syntax you describe.  Basic types(strings, ints, floats) are converted automatically by jython when going from some .py code into java.  If you want to be processing your own objects you have to start writing interface wrappers.

```
C:\>SET PATH=C:\jython2.5.2\bin;%PATH%

C:\>jython
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06)
[Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_24
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from javax.crypto import Cipher
>>> cipher = Cipher.getInstance('AES/CTR/NoPadding')
>>> cipher
javax.crypto.Cipher@1296d1d
>>>
```